# Using interruptions in switch case with the ATMEGA 328P

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, atmega, microchip

I'm trying to do a simple program with 3 buttons and interruptions, they are at PC1, PC2 and PC3, and i'm using them to change between cases, however, whenever i push one button, the other ones are activated.

I don't now exactly what is the problem, it's possible to work with 3 different interruptions in PORTC? Or whenever i push one the others will be activated?
My code is this one below, and the circuit is:
[image]
`

```
/*
 * Atividade Avaliativa 3.c
 *
 * Created: 30/11/2022 00:32:41
 * Author : Gustavo Feijó
 */

#include "def_principais.h"
#include "LCD.h"
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const unsigned char Segment[] PROGMEM = {0x30, 0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34,0x35,0x36,0x37,0x38,0x39
                                        }; //Hexadecimal dos numeros para o display.
volatile int Bot1=0;
volatile int Bot2=0;
volatile int Bot3=0;
volatile int i=0;
volatile int j=0;
volatile int m=0;
volatile int k=0;
volatile int h=0;
volatile int d=0;
volatile int Ah=0;
volatile int Ad=0;
volatile int Am=0;
int main(void)
{
    int modo=1;
    DDRD = 0xFF;
    DDRC = 0x01;
    DDRB = 0x0F;

    //TIMER 0 = 10ms
    TCCR0A |= 0x02;
    TCCR0B |= 0x05;
    OCR0A = 78;
    set_bit(TIMSK0, OCIE0A);


    //Timer 1 = 1s
    TCCR1A |= 0x00;
    TCCR1B |= ((1<<CS12)|(1<<CS10)|(1<<WGM12));
    OCR1A = 7812;
    set_bit(TIMSK1, OCIE1A);

    //Interrupções botões
    PCICR = 1<<PCIE1;
    PCMSK1 = (1<<PCINT11)|(1<<PCINT10)|(1<<PCINT9);

    sei();
    inic_LCD_4bits();

    while(1)
    {
        switch (modo)
        {
        case 0:
            cmd_LCD(0x01,0);
            if (Bot1==1)
            {
                Bot1=0;
                modo=1;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            cmd_LCD(0x8B,0);
            cmd_LCD(pgm_read_byte(&Segment[i]),1);
            cmd_LCD(0x8A,0);
            cmd_LCD(pgm_read_byte(&Segment[j]),1);
            cmd_LCD(0x89,0);
            cmd_LCD(0x3A,1);
            cmd_LCD(0x88,0);
            cmd_LCD(pgm_read_byte(&Segment[m]),1);
            cmd_LCD(0x87,0);
            cmd_LCD(pgm_read_byte(&Segment[k]),1);
            cmd_LCD(0x86,0);
            cmd_LCD(0x3A,1);
            cmd_LCD(0x85,0);
            cmd_LCD(pgm_read_byte(&Segment[h]),1);
            cmd_LCD(0x84,0);
            cmd_LCD(pgm_read_byte(&Segment[d]),1);
            if (Bot1==1)
            {
                Bot1=0;
                modo=0;
            }
            if (Bot2==1)
            {
                cpl_bit(PORTC,PC5);
                Bot2=0;
                modo=2;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            escreve_LCD("CU");
            if (Bot1==1)
            {
                Bot1=0;
                cmd_LCD(0x01,0);
                modo=1;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect)
{
    cpl_bit(PORTB,PB2);
}
//interrupaçao de 1S
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
    cpl_bit(PORTB,PB3);
    i++;
    if (i==10)
    {
        i=0;
        j++;
    }
    if (j==7)
    {
        j=0;
        m++;
    }
    if (m==10)
    {
        m=0;
        k++;
    }
    if (k==7)
    {
        k=0;
        h++;
    }
    if (h==5)
    {
        h=0;
        d++;
    }
    if(d==3)
    {
        d==0;
    }
}
ISR(PCINT1_vect) //interrupção externa 0, quando o botão é pressionado o LED troca de estado
{
    if(!tst_bit(PINC,PINC1))
    {
        Bot1++;
    }
    else if(!tst_bit(PINC,PINC2))
    {
        Bot2++;
    }
    else if(!tst_bit(PINC,PINC3))
    {
        Bot3++;
    }
}
```

`

Comment: `ISR(PCINT1_vect)` looks wrong.  You have inverted the tests for C2 and C3, both will be incremented on interrupt by C1.  You are rather optimistic too about `(Bot1==1)` etc;  you need to deal with switch bounce.  Better perhaps to ask how to do button input than how to fix this flawed code.  Often it is better to poll the switches in a timer than to use the GPIO interrupt.  Makes denounce simpler, as you will need a timer for that in any case.